# How does it implement this chart with highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, frontend

https://institutional.fidelity.com/app/item/RD_13569_45180/the-art-and-science-of-investment-decision-making.html

There is a very nice graph and pie chart under `Investment Decision-Making in 2016`.

I know it is highcharts now. I want to write something similar. But I can't find any chart type similar in its [document](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types).
Could you tell me what kind of chart it is? And how to put different data items inside the bubble.

Comment: It is highchart 4.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a combination of **line**, **bubble** and **pie** series.

Line series (alternative: scatter with `lineWidth` > 0) lies under the bubbles. All interaction with this series should be disabled (hover state, tooltip, etc.).

Text inside the bubble is data label (`dataLabels.enabled` property should be set to `true`). You can manage its content in `dataLabels.formatter`callback function.

You can handle showing/adding pie (donut) charts in `plotOptions.bubble.point.events.mouseover` callback function. Text in the middle of a donut can be rendered via `SVGRenderer.text()`.

All options that I mentioned can be found in the **API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/